# What is Repository Key in SonarQube Plugin ?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I develop a plugin for Sonarqube and I follow the [sonarqube plugin code example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example). But I don't understand what is the REPO_KEY and REPO_NAME constant in [this file](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/rules/FooLintRulesDefinition.java)

This Key is use in parameter of this [function](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/latest/apidocs/org/sonar/api/rule/RuleKey.html#of-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Is there a link with the xml file who define the rules ?

Thank you.

TF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository is the group of rules provided by the plugin. For example the Findbugs plugin defines a repository which is key is "findbugs" and display name is "Findbugs".

You can find more information about the XML format here: http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/6.3/apidocs/org/sonar/api/server/rule/RulesDefinitionXmlLoader.html